# From a matrix, create 2 vectors which contain even elements of columns and row, the other has the odd

Tags: c

I exercised myself on the basics, and i want to try something harder, but wihtout an example i don't know how to start a programm like this(I don't know how to create the 2 vectors starting from the matrix,mainly; and i don't know how to link them with subprograms).

The exercise asks to create a float matrix(read it from a .txt file).From the matrix, you need to create 2 vectors that:

-Vectors need to be created with the even\odd columns and row elements of the matrix.(Their index.I mean, the position these values have in the matrix.Ex: The value 3 is at the position 2,3=5 The element is in an odd position)

-The vectors  need to be organized in ascending order(i know the algorithm).

-Their scalar product(i know the algorithm).

Every step of this needs to be done as a subprogram(i know how it works, but how to link every step...). 
What i was able to do, wat just to create the Matrix, reading it from the .txt. I feel that i can create those 2 vectors from the matrix too, but not as the exercises asks(One with even elements from row and columns, the other with the odd elements). It even asks to create a struct with these vectors, but i want to ignore it atm. This is what wrote till now:

EDIT: I wrote all the exercise text to be as clear as possible(who knows, maybe you could like it as well.)I can do almost everything but the first step where it asks about the 2 vectors(without it i can't continue).

EDIT 2: I wrote teSt instead of teXt.I'll keep it because i thought they had the same meaning, but it's not so. I started "coding" during free time a month ago because i like it. I'm sorry for the misunderstood...

EDIT 3:  There's an error in the second vector,it's:[...3.1,0]

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoWlQ.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 100

int main()
{
    float mat[DIM][DIM];
    float a, b;
    int i, j;

    //FilePointer.
    FILE  *fpIN;
    FILE *fpOUT;

    //Reading the file.
    fpIN=fopen("input.txt","r");

    if(fpIN==NULL) {
        printf("There was an error opening the file.");
        return 1;
    }

    //Reading matrix dimension.
    fscanf(fpIN,"%f",&a);
    fscanf(fpIN,"%f\n\n",&b);

    //Matrix cycle for.
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        for( j=0; j<b; j++)
        {
            if(j==b-1)
                fscanf(fpIN,"%f\n",&mat[i][j]);
            else
                fscanf(fpIN,"%f",&mat[i][j]);
        }

    //Reading the matrix.
    printf(" The current %f %f matrix is:\n",a,b);
    for( i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for( j=0; j<b; j++)
            printf("%10f",mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fpIN);
}
```

Comment: "*This is what wrote till now*" <- without an actual question in place, I assume you expect someone else to write the rest for you?

Comment: No, i just wrote everything to be as clear as possible. I just would like to know how i could create those 2 vectors mainly, using that indexes within the matrix(that's why i posted it). I would never ask someone to write the code. Sorry if the post has a meaning like that...

Comment: Well it's hard to imagine what to answer here? A "vector" would probably be a simple array, you "create" it by defining it?

Comment: I feel like i should write again the post,i explained it very bad, you're right... I mean a simple array as "vector", and with create i meant "define"... I'd start to improve my english

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, it's just hard to understand the actual problem. A vector holding a row? something like `float vector[DIM];`, then just use a loop to copy the values you want there.

Comment: unrelated "pro tip": Use `double`. The only "benefit" of `float` is less memory used, irrelevant most of the time. The precision of `float` is too bad for most serious use and it isn't any faster than `double`.

Comment: I added an example image( as link) into the text.What i need is looking at the position of the value into the matrix(seeing if it's even or odd) and then adding them into 2 "vectors" Ps: I'll use double so!